Test pollution with `toHaveStyle`
When I run tests individually they pass. But when I run the test file which includes all those tests, the first assertion of toHaveStyle passes then the rest fail!!
What is the proper setup to ensure there's no test pollution in this case?
I'm using Vitest and React Testing Library.

Run yarn test
Tests pass

